# Number of POST requests processed by Web API endpoint

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api

I am building an ASP.NET Web API application and i'd like to know the number of requests processed in one second? This is my code.

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public async void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        await Method(value)
    }    
}
```

I have a Test Client, this program send 1000 post requests to my Web API to the same time. It is assumed that my controller should process 10,000 requests to the same time. How I can know how many requests processed in one second? Have you got any idea?

Comment: Can you not insert a function that stores a value in a file or in SQL? Just either run a stored procedure that increments a table field, or do an insert each time and count the total.

Comment: Use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your test client.

Comment: @Lopsided: SQL will add significant overhead.

Comment: Your current code doesn't return anything, it's literally 'fire and forget'. Make sure you return some http status, like 200 OK, then your test client will be sure a request was processed.

Comment: Well it's an API, so you could offload the SQL transaction to another server and fire it via js at the same time you make ur POST request. I don't think one bit of data will slow you down too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think performance counters is the best way to achieve this (Low overhead both in terms of perf overhead and in terms of effort to set it up). You can use built-in performance counters listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4%28v=vs.140%29.aspx or you can also create custom perf counters like what is outlined in http://byterot.blogspot.com/2013/04/Monitor-your-ASP-NET-Web-API-application-using-your-own-custom-counters.html